# Border of pictures are not coming in longtable

Tags: floats, longtable

[image]

```
\begin{longtable}{|lllllllll|} 
        %   [ht] 
        \caption{Create } \\ 
        %\label{step 3}
        \hline
        \multicolumn{3}{|l|}{\textbf{Prefix}} & \multicolumn{2}{l|}{\textbf{Class label}} & \multicolumn{2}{l|}{\textbf{Intersection}}\\
        \hline
        \endfirsthead
        \multicolumn{6}{c}%
        {\tablename\ \thetable\ -- \textit{Continued from previous page}} \\
        \hline
        \multicolumn{3}{|l|}{\textbf{Prefix}} & \multicolumn{2}{l|}{\textbf{Class label}} & \multicolumn{2}{l|}{\textbf{Intersection}}\\
        \hline
        \endhead
        \hline \multicolumn{6}{r}{\textit{Continued on next page}} \\
        \endfoot
        \hline
        \endlastfoot
        %   \begin{tabular} {lllllll}[ht]\\ 


        %   \hline \multicolumn{3}{|l|}{\textbf{Prefix}} & \multicolumn{2}{l|}{\textbf{Class label}} & \multicolumn{2}{l|}{\textbf{Intersection}} \\ \hline 

        \multicolumn{7}{|l|}{\textbf{Begin}}\\ \hline

        \multicolumn{7}{|l|}{\textbf{Initial}}\\ \hline

        \parbox[|c|]{2cm}{
    \includegraphics[scale=0.40,height=8 cm,width=10 cm]{initialfgist.jpg}} \\ \hline
        \end{longtable}
```

The right side and top border of the picture is not coming.
Please tell what am i doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1):

```
\parbox[|c|]{2cm}{
    \includegraphics[scale=0.40,height=8 cm,width=10 cm]
```

This specifies a 10cm wide image in a 2cm wide box, so overprinting is expected.
At least it would specify that if it was `\parbox{2cm}` but  `\parbox[|c|]` is 
a syntax error (although latex does not report it as such), the optional argument can only be `c`, `t` or `b`.

You just want to specify *one* of `scale`, `width` and `height` and you do not want the `\parbox` at all.

Comment: I tried \parbox{12 cm} but still the borders are not showing

Comment: @SOUMYADEEPBASUCHOWDHURY You have not specified any borders other than the table border. delete the `\parbox`

Answer (score 1):

The `cellspace` package is here for that: it defines minimal vertical spacig at the top and bottom of cell in columns with specifier prefixed by the letter `S` (or `C` if you use `siunitx`). I also simplified your code and corrected it where it was faulty:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{array, longtable}
\usepackage{cellspace}
\setlength\cellspacetoplimit{3pt}
\setlength\cellspacebottomlimit{3pt}


\begin{document}

\begin{longtable}{|*{7}{Sl}|}
    \caption{Create } \\
    %\label{step 3}
    \hline
    \multicolumn{3}{|Sl|}{\textbf{Prefix}} & \multicolumn{2}{l|}{\textbf{Class label}} & \multicolumn{2}{l|}{\textbf{Intersection}}\\
    \hline
    \endfirsthead
    \multicolumn{6}{Sc}%
    {\tablename\ \thetable\ -- \textit{Continued from previous page}} \\
    \hline
    \multicolumn{3}{|Sl|}{\textbf{Prefix}} & \multicolumn{2}{l|}{\textbf{Class label}} & \multicolumn{2}{l|}{\textbf{Intersection}}\\
    \hline
    \endhead
    \hline \multicolumn{7}{Sr}{\textit{Continued on next page}} \\
    \endfoot
    \hline
    \multicolumn{7}{|Sl|}{\textbf{Begin}}\\ 
    \hline
    \multicolumn{7}{|Sl|}{\textbf{Initial}}\\ 
    \hline
    \includegraphics[scale=0.40]{initialfgist.jpg} & & & & & & \\
    \hline
    \end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I am not good at latex. When i am using your code, something like this comes as output https://www.overleaf.com/2631467btbnvb#/6946991/

Comment: I see. Change the value of `scale=…` so that the table does not overflow the right margin, or choose `width=…`  to suit your needs (it the wil be automatically scaled). . Anyway, do you really need `7`  columns? Your code does not use them.